# What are the alternatives to a scheduler that uses a linked list?

Tags: embedded, scheduling

I'm reading an article on [real-time kernels](http://intranet.daiict.ac.in/~ranjan/esp2005/paper/real_time_esc_240_260.pdf), and the author explains how to implement a scheduler for tasks with a linked list. He also states that this is not the best way since tasks are inserted and removed based on priority; however, he doesn't explain what those other methods are.

What are the other methods for implementing a scheduler other than a linked list?

Comment: A linked list is an implementation of a collection. an Array, Doubly-Linked List, Binary Tree, Hash list etc are possible alternatives. The reason a Linked List is a poor choice for a scheduler is that you must traverse the list in order to find an element, which is normally ordered by priority. Which goes against real-time requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a good hard look at the Queue Data structure.   If you have a queue for each priority level, then you can start at the highest priority queue, and process until the queue is empty, then step to the next priority query, until you have hit all of the priorities.

Having tasks at the same priority level in a queue, allows you to guarentee that each task gets at least one quantum of processing, before it is thrown into the tail of (possibly another) queue.

Of course for real-time processsing, you want quick response to an interrupt.  Perhaps some sort of Priority Queue might be applicable.

Answer (score 1):

There's lots, for instance could have been a double linked list, so for inserting a low priority task, could have searched backwards from the tail.

You could implement the schedule as in list of tasks with anything from an array to a B-Tree, which one you use depends on what you are scheduling.

Linked list, if it's fairly short might be the optimal solution.